# Power BI Report Level Measures on Live query to OLAP cube

Tags: excel, ssis, ssas, powerbi, olap

I am new to Power BI world.

In my company we have a connection to an OLAP cube, where we connect using a live query through Analysis Services.

As the [Power BI documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-analysis-services-tabular-data), on May 2nd, 2017 they added a feature to use report level measures but this approach **does not work** on multidimensional databases (yet).

I need to replicate some Excel workbooks (where they use DAX functions) in order to use all the Power BI features where Excel has no power.

Since I can't edit the queries, the relationships or create any kind of measures for this. How should I use a different approach to do these calculations that the Excel workbooks do?

Comment: I'm running into a similar general situation - needing Excel features at the reporting level within PBI - I've come to the realization (for now at least) that PBI is too limited still in its current state. My only solution for now is for what I can only do in Excel I'm publishing to PBI. Still searching for better solutions.

Comment: @Hatt, I think PBI is only limited when come to live connections. If you are not connecting to a cube then you can use measures. In general, if not using a live connection at all then you can use Excel features and more.